# Deriving a Generic instance of my type doesn't automatically create other instances as intended

Tags: generics, haskell

Following the instructions in the Data.Binary documentation, I'm trying to use GHC.Generics to generate a Binary instance of a custom type.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

module BinaryTest where

import Data.Binary
import GHC.Generics (Generic)

data Option = Yes | No deriving (Generic)

instance Binary Option
```

This compiles, but yeilds 2 warnings telling me that I haven't provided definitions for `get` or `put`; and sure enough, if I attempt to use encode or decode from Binary, it crashes with an error that `get`/`put` isn't defined.
Does anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: It works for me.  What version of the libraries and GHC are you using?

Comment: Most likely not using an up to date version of GHC, I think. This is a rather recent (within the last year or two?) feature.

Comment: 7.6.3. It says that it needs minimum 7.2.

Comment: I downloaded the latest version, and it works now. Must be a bug in 7.6.3. Thanks

Comment: I think it is more likely that you had an old version of the `Data.Binary` module installed that didn't provide a default implementation for generic types.

Comment: The documentation said that it was compatible past 7.2, and I had a version from past 7.2 (as I've already stated). Unless for some reason I had modules from an older version installed. That's unlikely though, as this was only the second time that I've installed GHC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the latest version (7.8.3) solved it. It must be a bug in 7.6.3